# Can anybody recommend a free xslt tool?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm looking for a free xslt debugging tool for Windows. Is anybody using anything worth recommending? Appreciate any advice, thanks.

Comment: Note that when you develop XSLT professionally, then the features you get with a commercial product such as Oxygen might very well be worth the money.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://free.editix.com/download.html
Powerfull tool!

Edit:

Since people are having issues reading the comment section. This app is not free anymore. Original answer is from 2010.

They have a community edition that is still free but you have to compile it yourself with Java: https://github.com/AlexandreBrillant/Editix-xml-editor

Comment: That really is very good (and wasn’t even on my radar). Thanks a lot.

Comment: What about another This Answer is useful +1 because im so sexy and im in need of some reputation:D? And your welcome ;)!

Comment: I gave you the first a deserved upvote, thank you for this!

Comment: My corporate firewall blocked that site due to malware risks.

Comment: Is there a free version?

Comment: This is not a free tool

Comment: @nZeus it was 6 years ago.

Comment: When I click on that link I get http://www.editix.com/download.html which is not free

Comment: @yannis If you read the comments you would've seen that this app was indeed free (8 years ago already). Posted in 2010 x)

Comment: In fact, if you checked the site a little better you would've noticed a community edition you can still get for free.

Answer (score 3):

**I have been using the XSelerator for almost 10 years** and have never found a better tool XSLT IDE.

**XSelerator's most valuable features are**:

1. XSLT Debugger for MSXML3 and MSXML4.
2. Intellisense (prompting the xslt instructions, their attributes and the enumeration of possible attribute values.
3. Dynamic intellisense: prompting with template names or with modes or with parameter names.
4. XSLT 2.0 intellisense.
5. One-click invocation of many XSLT processors.
6. One can easily add a new XSLT processor to XSelerator.

Comment: but where can one find Xselerator these days?  the [sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xselerator) has gone DOA.

Comment: @mcdrewski: Here: http://sf.net/projects/xselerator

Comment: Good tool BUT it won't work in 64bit :(

Comment: @nixon: `This is not true`: I am using it on my 64 bit computers. The only thing is that in most OSes you must run it as administator -- it is convenient to change the properties or have a shortcut with properties set to "run as administrator.

Comment: Hi, yes i just discovered the same which is great, given that VS2010 64 bit crashes on xslt debug !

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Where is it now? Project playing hide and seek with us?