# Auto generate XSL to convert input XML to given output XML

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

Are there any open-source or commercial tools available that auto generate XSL based on an input file and the expected output file?  We are looking for a tool to which we can give the 2 XML files and that will be converted to an XSL file.

I have found the commercial [Altova Technote](http://www.altova.com/technote20.html) that is supposed to have this functionality. I haven't yet tested it.

I would like to know if there are any other open-source or commercial tools available.

Comment: Your question makes no sense, unless you are asking for a tool that, given an input XML file A and an output XML file B, creates an XSL that will convert A to B. You should know that questions asking for someone to recommend/find a tool are generally off-topic here.

Comment: Indeed, please be more specific. Is it a) given XML + unknown XSL transformation = given XML output or b) given XML + given different XML = unknown XSD schema or c) given XML + given different XML = unknown XSL transformation? From your current description I think it is option c), which really makes no sense, because XSL can only be generated if the expected output is known. Please update your question and tags accordingly.

Comment: @Jim Garriosn, I opologise.  I was not aware of this rule, as I had seen similar questions that were answered.  Just would like to clarify that I didn't expect someone to 'find' the tool for me, just wanted to know, if anybody was aware of any tools.  i will refrain from asking these types of questions in the future

Comment: @Thomas W - I have 2 XMLs - and I would be converting first XML to the second one.  And wanted to know, if any tool can generate the xsl if I have the input and output xmls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you Dijkgraaf.  As you mentioned, BizTalk is a bit expensive for our purposes at this time.  I have found an open source [CPOL](http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx) licenced [tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18626/XML-to-XML-Mapping-Tool) in CodeProject.  Adding it here, for someone looking for a similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft BizTalk can do what Altova DiffDog can do and more using it's schema generation/editing and mapping tools in Visual Studio, but is probably a bit over the top/expensive if all you want to do is create those XSL files.     There is a previous thread [about some other XSLT tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699854/can-anybody-recommend-a-free-xslt-tool).